# Error on DateTime.ParseExact

Tags: c#, .net

I have a date in an oracle database, that I query on. This date looks like:

```
5/3/2016 (after I remove the time portion)
```

I try to convert this date to a `DateTime`. I am using:

```
ParseExact(String, String, IFormatProvider)
```

I am doing something wrong, which I can't figure out.
My code is shown below. Notice that the variable called "res", has the value `5/3/2016` as described above

```
try {
    while(reader.Read()) {
        string res = reader[0].ToString().Substring(0, 8);
        mailer.SendSmtpMail4dev("Result: " + res);
        mailer.SendSmtpMail4dev("Result: " + DateTime.ParseExact(res, "dd-MM-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }
} catch(Exception e) { ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for `DateTime.ParseExact` The format of the input string and the format string should be the same, so use:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(res, "d/M/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

In your case the supplied date is `5/3/2016` and you are specifying that the format is `"dd-MM-yyyy"` such conversions are not possible. if you need to change the format means you can do like the following:

```
string res = "5/2/2016";
DateTime givenDate = DateTime.ParseExact(res, "d/M/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string newFormatedDate = givenDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Comment: Single digit value like 5/3/2016 may fail. See my ans for the updated format.

Comment: Note that this works because you use `InvariantCulture` which supresses the ["/" Custom Format Specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#dateSeparator) which normally replaces `/` with the current culture's date separator. Another way would be: `DateTime.ParseExact("5/3/2016", "d'/'M'/'yyyy",null)` which escapes this specifier.

Answer (score 1):

since your `res` date is `dd/MM/yyyy` format but you have tried to cast is as `dd-MM-yyyy`, in `DateTime.ParseExact()` you have to provide datetime and format string as same format,  correct code will be like this

```
mailer.SendSmtpMail4dev("Result: " + DateTime.ParseExact(res, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(res, "d/M/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Refer to the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) for details

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
DateTime.ParseExact(res, "d/M/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a *date* why do you convert it to `String`

```
// What if server's NLS_* settings are changed? What does 8 stand for?
reader[0].ToString().Substring(0, 8);
```

and then `Parse` again? If `reader[0]` is a date use `DateTime`:

```
try {
  while(reader.Read()) {
    // 0th field is date, then treat it as being date
    DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(reader[0]);

    //TODO: put the right formats here
    mailer.SendSmtpMail4dev("Result: " + date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
    mailer.SendSmtpMail4dev("Result: " + date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
  }
}
catch(Exception e) { 
  ...
}
```

Comment: The .Substring is just a temporary solution, to make the conversion work. I had to quickly move out the time portion, and this is the quickest way I know, but I am aware that this is not the way to go :-)

Comment: @MOR_SNOW: If you want to remove time part, remove it in a *right* way: `date = date.Date;`

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem is marked above, but I just want to state something important, so that others might save some time. Some suggested solutions, suggest doing: `DateTime.ParseExact(res, "dd/MM/yyyy" ...)` which also seems to be in many other examples on the net, so I'm not saying it's wrong. However. This didn't work for me, I spent some time, before I tried doing:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(res, "d/M/yyyy" ...)
```

Notice that in the later solution, there is only one d, and one M. 
But my main problem, like everyone pointed out, was probably that I was using:

```
"dd-MM-yyyy" instead of "dd/MM/yyyy" (which is the same format as the oracle value)
```

Hope this will save you some time